# string consisting of letters, spaces, a hyphen and single quotation mark only

Tags: java, string

Im new to programming and I want to make a program about something and in this program, the person must enter a name and their name can consist of letters, spaces, a single quotation mark and a hyphen only. And if the name has an illegal character, the user must re-enter the name. I want to code this using a for loop, how can i do it?

Comment: There are many ways of doing it, what have u tried?

Answer (score 0):

You may define a custom method to check whether the string is legal or not. You may use charAt(int) method to check each character and Character.isLetter(char) method of java to check if it is a letter.
eg.

```
public boolean checkString(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (!(Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i)) || 
              str.charAt(i) == ' ' || 
              str.charAt(i) == '-' || 
              str.charAt(i) == '\'')) 
        {
            System.out.println("Re-enter the string");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i see, can i add a do while loop after?